# is that possible to serv hls and dash mpeg both at a time

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp, mpeg-dash

actually i'm a kind a newbie to the Nginx RTMP server. I had setup my nginx.conf file to accept both hls and dash-mpeg. but the now problem is at a once I can able to serve either of the hls or dash-mpeg. so now my question is that possible to serve both hls and dash-mpeg at the same time for two different videos? I'm streaming video from OBS Studio.
here are my MPEG and hls code in nginx.conf file

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
    chunk_size 4000;

    application show {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /nginx/hls/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
        deny play all;
    }
    application dash {
            live on;
            dash on;
            dash_path /nginx/dash;

    }
}
```

}

thank you advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that is possible you can serve how many you need. it having 2 options(as i tried,) 
1. you can use the OBS studio for streaming. or
2. You can use the FFmpeg command in the terminal to achieve it. 
 I suggest you use two terminals or 2 windows of OBS studio to make it possible. but be sure that your network is as strong to support the streaming 2 videos at once. try it and let us to know. and I guess you need to add some more configuration in the dash config. for more details refer to this page.[peer5.com](https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/), if it is working give an upvote too;-)